# CSRF - Back Button Support

Tags: php, csrf

I've been adding this CSRF class for my PHP site:

https://github.com/BKcore/NoCSRF

It's working well, however the downside of this seems to be that it doesn't allow the user to click the back button to return to a previous page, as each time they click the back button they get the:

Invalid CSRF token. Please try again.

error and need to go back to the very first page, which in a 10 page form submission site can be a pain. This is my first time implementing CSRF using this class and I'm just following the example from the site:

https://github.com/BKcore/NoCSRF/blob/master/example/example.php

Is it possible to modify this to allow the user to click the back button and still use the CSRF protection?